# How can I get cat to add a literal line break after each line? (for echo -e) in bash

Tags: bash

How can I get cat to add a literal line break after each line? (for echo -e to read it) in bash

```
root@111[~]# cat names 
Joe Smith
John St. John
Jeff Jefferson
root@111 [~]# var=`cat names`;echo -e $var
Joe Smith John St. John Jeff Jefferson
```

I want the second command to produce output identical to the first.

Comment: If you don't use quotes, `$var` gets string-split and glob-expanded, meaning each word in the string is passed to `echo` as a separate argument. So, `Joe` is the first argument, `Smith` is the second, `John` is the third, etc.

Comment: ...in that case, why would you *expect* it to separate `Smith` and `John` in a different way from how it separates `Joe` and `Smith`?

Comment: As such, this isn't a problem with `cat` at all; it's a problem with how you're using `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use `echo -e`; it adds no value here, and [the POSIX standard for echo](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html) explicitly disallows the behavior you're expecting it to provide (a POSIX-compliant `echo` with XSI extensions will honor backslash escapes without `-e`; a POSIX-compliant `echo` without XSI extensions will just echo the literal string `-e` and still ignore backslash escapes; the GNU implementation that changes its behavior based on whether `-e` breaks both XSI and baseline versions of the standard).

Second, use quotes:

```
echo "$var"
```

...or, better, skip `echo` altogether in favor of `printf`:

```
printf '%s\n' "$var"
```